# What replaces std::codecvt_utf8 in C++17 or how else do I convert an int to a u32 string?

Tags: c++17

I noticed on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8) that this and related things in the `<codecvt>` header are deprecated in C++17.

So what's the alternative that is supported?

I'm trying to convert an `int` into a `std::u32srting` in order to properly support unicode. I was going to convert with `std::to_string` or `std::to_wstring` before using `std::wstring_convert` but noticed it's deprecated. I would much rather use the correct most recent standard.

Comment: Perhaps you [*shouldn't*](http://utf8everywhere.org/) convert to UTF-32?

Comment: Okay... but don't I have the same problem converting to UTF-8 @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: That's the nice thing about UTF-8, it's a *byte* encoding. Which means you can basically use `char` and `std::string` without any problems. :)

Comment: @NeomerArcana: "*I'm trying to convert an int into a std::u32srting*" What do you mean by that exactly? Are you trying to do integer-to-string conversion (the integer 23 becomes the string "23"), or are you trying to interpret the `int` as a Unicode codepoint (the integer 2450 becomes the codepoint U+0992).

Comment: @NicolBolas trying to make the string "23"